# trying to get propert of non object error

Tags: php

Following errors show up for the code given below:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$duration in C:\wamp\www\temp\yy.php
>
> trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\temp\yy.php

How to resolve?

```
$q = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$a,$b&destinations=$c,$d&mode=driving&sensor=false";
$json = file_get_contents($q);
$details = json_decode($json);
$d=$details->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text;
```

Comment: do a `var_dump` of `$json` to make sure it is valid json. Also, do a `var_dump` of `$details` to make sure it is an object.

Comment: What have you in these (`origins=$a,$b&destinations=$c,$d`) variables ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
if($details->rows[0]->elements[0]->status == 'OK') {
    $text = $details->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text;
}
```

If no results were returned then you may get following as `$details->rows[0]->elements[0]`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => ZERO_RESULTS
)
```

If a result were returned then you will get something like this as `$details->rows[0]->elements[0]`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [distance] => stdClass Object
    (
        [text] => 1Â 716 km
        [value] => 1715523
    )

    [duration] => stdClass Object
    (
        [text] => 3 jours 19 heures
        [value] => 329133
    )

    [status] => OK
)
```

So, if `$details->rows[0]->elements[0]->status` is `OK` then there is a `distance` and a `duration` property and each one contains an `stdClass` object with two properties as `text` and `value`. Make sure you are passing right data within your variables (`$a`, `$b`, `$c` and `$d`).

Try this for example:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

Comment: A much more complete answer than the one I gave. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're receiving is telling you exactly what the problem is. The `duration` property is not found on the object returned by `json_decode`; the above query you are making in the referenced code block (i.e. [this one](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%24a,%24b&destinations=%24c,%24d&mode=driving&sensor=false)) returns the following JSON:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Catamarca Province, Argentina" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Augsburg, Germany" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Looking at this, there is no `duration` element returned in the above, therefore the following call:

```
$json = file_get_contents($q);
$details = json_decode($json);
$d=$details->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text;
```

Will result in the error you're seeing.

You can use error handling (e.g. `try...catch`) to get the duration and the text if it exists, or test to see if the property exists, etc.

Basically, what it boils down to is that without additional code, you can't rely on the fact that `duration` will be an element of that returned `JSON` and you have to account for it.

Comment: There are some variables `origins=$a,$b&destinations=$c,$d`.

Comment: Good catch I didn't even see that in his query; however while you might expect duration to be there there are clearly still cases that it may not. Additional handling is still recommended. Based on the author's answer regarding the variables, I'll update my answer (or retract it).